# GET request error 404 on ionic mobile application

Tags: angular, ionic2

here is my first project on ionic2 on github:

https://github.com/eshk12/firstApp/tree/API-inserted

There is a function `getCurrency();` on `network.ts` that pull JSON data from an API server,

the first api url was: `http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=CAD`
and on mobile the get request return 404 error as you can see below.

so I thought the api Have security from request from apps and etc, so i write php script that get the data of it:
`http://build-net.co.il/apps/currency/currency.php?base=USD`
and change it inside the code, I have reinstall the application and still I get 404 error code from my server.

while I build the app and test it on ionic engine "ionic serve"
all goes well, but when I compile the project into ".apk"(idk about ios) file, this error came up(I have used chrome inspector to get the problem):

```
main.js:27 function fired!
http://build-net.co.il/apps/currency/currency.php?base=USD Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
main.js:5 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Response with status: 404 Not Found for URL: http://build-net.co.il/apps/currency/currency.php?base=USDt.handleError @ main.js:5
main.js:5 ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:t.handleError @ main.js:5
main.js:5 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Response with status: 404 Not Found for URL: http://build-net.co.il/apps/currency/currency.php?base=USD
    at s (polyfills.js:3)
    at s (polyfills.js:3)
    at polyfills.js:3
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (main.js:7)
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at e.runTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at i (polyfills.js:3)
    at XMLHttpRequest.invoke (polyfills.js:3)t.handleError @ main.js:5
polyfills.js:3 Unhandled Promise rejection: e ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: e undefinedo @ polyfills.js:3
polyfills.js:3 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Response with status: 404 Not Found for URL: http://build-net.co.il/apps/currency/currency.php?base=USD(…)o @ polyfills.js:3
```

I hope you guys may solve this problem,

Comment: What does a packet sniffer say? Is the expected call made? Does the same call work from an ordinary browser?

Comment: hey thanks for your quick response,
and yes the same call work fine from a browser(chrome,firefox)

Answer (score 1):

after i have done some research about this issue I have found the solution.
acording to the Cordova update 4.0.0

> Major Changes [...] - Whitelist functionality is now provided via
>   plugin (CB-7747) The whitelist has been enhanced to be more secure and
>   configurable Setting of Content-Security-Policy is now supported by
>   the framework (see details in plugin readme) You will need to add the
>   new cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin Legacy whitelist behaviour is
>   still available via plugin (although not recommended).

I installed [Cordova Whitelist plugin.](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist) And added:

```
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
```

Into `config.xml` file.